# how to handle internationalization on the chrome web store?

Tags: internationalization, google-chrome-extension

I would like that my Chrome extension title to be on the relevant language on the Chrome Web Store. I couldn't find anything about it on the developer dashboard. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's described [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/i18n.html). You would need to set your extension name in manifest through locale var, and then it will be different in web store depending on user's language.